# Replacing first two digits in a phone number using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to replace the first two digits of the phone numbers we store from a 61 to a 0 using a SQL automation in Marketing Cloud, however, nothing has worked so far.

The field name is Account_Phone_Number__c and MC needs to start all SQL statements with SELECT.

Essentially I need a SQL statement which replaces the first two digits (61) with a 0, ensuring it won't replace ANY 61 but just the first two in the field.

The closest I got was below however the pesky SELECT keeps throwing me out.

```
UPDATE Account_Phone_Number__c
SET num = '0'+substring(num, 3, len(num))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get around not being able to use UPDATE, your best bet is to combine [stuff()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a [CASE](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/) statement.  See below for sample query:

```
select   case
         when Account_Phone_Number_c like '61%' then stuff(Account_Phone_Number_C, 1, 2, '0')
         else Account_Phone_Number_c
         end as Account_Phone_Number_c
from     yourDE
```